# How can I display these subfigures without cropping them?

Tags: graphics, formatting, subfig

I am trying to create a figure comprised of 2 subfigures, either side-by-side on landscape mode or one on top of another in portrait. I have the following code to create the figure, but could use help in creating a figure that isn't cropped out and shows the whole graph, as I'm relatively new to latex!

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/repeatability.png}
  \caption{Anisotropic with the repeatability limit shown}
  \label{fig:repeatabilityMosaic}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/reproducibility.png}
  \caption{Anisotropic with the reproducibility limit shown}
  \label{fig:reproducabilityMosaic}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Cumulative sum of the percentage of thresholded regions for each of 400 images in a mosaic, with the repeatability and reproducibility limits in shaded}
\label{fig:repeatabilityAndreproducibility}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `[width=\linewidth]` instead of `[scale=...]`.  Also, put an `\fbox` around `\includegraphics` to see if you have unwanted white space in the image itself.

Comment: hi @JohnKormylo, thank you for this. How do youse \fbox? I've used the following but it no longer compiles the image! {\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
 \framebox{%

Comment: `\fbox{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`.  Setting `\fboxsep=0pt` helps, but isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `subcaption` from version 1.3 onward support environment `\subfloat` of `subfig` package (as way for transition from `subfig` to `subcaption`). Using it, your code can be a bit shorter:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}    % Dummy text
\setlength\fboxrule{0.2pt} % frame rule width
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}    % > 0pt if you want to see yellow padding
\newcommand\cfbox[1]{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{#1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\kant[1][1-2]

    \begin{figure}[tbh]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth, height=4cm}
\subfloat[Anisotropic with the repeatability limit shown
        \label{fig:repeatabilityMosaic}]{\includegraphics{figures/repeatability.png}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[Anisotropic with the reproducibility limit shown
        \label{fig:reproducabilityMosaic}]{\includegraphics{figures/reproducibility.png}}

\caption{Cumulative sum of the percentage of thresholded regions for each of 400 images in a mosaic, with the repeatability and reproducibility limits in shaded}
\label{fig:repeatabilityAndreproducibility}
    \end{figure}

\kant[1][3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
From image in question can be concluded, that your images has white (empty) space at left side of images. If this is a case you can see if you insert images in frame:

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/repeatability.png}}
  \caption{Anisotropic with the repeatability limit shown}
  \label{fig:repeatabilityMosaic}
\end{subfigure}
```

If frame is not tied to image, that you have two options:

- strip images (about what you complain), or
- with some tool dedicated to image processing strip out this space from image

How images are generated? If for them use for example `pgfplots` package, that image should be correctly clipped. In the case that you use some other software, than you check its setting for export of image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on `\subcaptionbox` macro from `subcaption` package. I also added `\captionsetup`s to show you can separately format captions for all floats, only figures, or even subfigures depending on which optional argument you add: `[figure]`, `[subfigure]` or nothing--also works for `[table]` or `[subtable]`.

Currently figures are placed next to each other with a separator `\hfill`, which adapts a gap to move both images far to left and to right. If you want figures to stack vertically, remove `\hfill`, insert an empty line followed by `\vspace{\floatsep}`; `\floatsep` is a defined length name that corresponds to a size of a gap between images placed at the top of a page.

I made a custom macro `\cfbox{}` which draws a red frame around an image. If you want a yellow padding added to each image, change `\fboxsep` to something higher than 0pt. This should help to figure out if white space around an image (between red frame and an image) is a part of an image.

I don't have access to your files so the document is compiled in `demo` mode, where figures are substituted by black boxes. Remove it in your draft to get your images back.

[image]

EDIT. Just a small note. `\centering` in the current code does not do anything because both floats span the whole space of the page width (due to `\hfill`). However, if you decide to arrange them vertically, without centering, both images will be left aligned. If you change `\hfill` to a fixed gap, you will also need `\centering`. Therefore, I have left it in the code.

```latex
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\captionsetup{position=bottom, format=hang}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=6pt}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=6pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}        % For fcolorbox
\usepackage{kantlipsum}    % Dummy text
\setlength\fboxrule{0.2pt} % frame rule width
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}    % > 0pt if you want to see yellow padding
\newcommand\cfbox[1]{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1-2]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth, height=4cm}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{%
        Anisotropic with the repeatability limit shown
        \label{fig:repeatabilityMosaic}%
    }{\cfbox{\includegraphics{figures/repeatability.png}}}%
    \hfill
    % \vspace{\floatsep}   % leave an empty line before
    \subcaptionbox{%
        Anisotropic with the reproducibility limit shown
        \label{fig:reproducabilityMosaic}%
    }{\cfbox{\includegraphics{figures/reproducibility.png}}}

    \caption{Cumulative sum of the percentage of thresholded regions for each of 400 images in a mosaic, with the repeatability and reproducibility limits in shaded}
    \label{fig:repeatabilityAndreproducibility}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][3-4]
\end{document}
```